# Inject objects into partials

Tags: angularjs

I have an object like this:

```
{
"first": {...},
"second": {...},
.....
}
```

Now I want to edit all subobjects. Every subobject looks the same and has the same functionality (CRUD). I cannot use ng-repeat, because I want the subobjects on specific places on the page.

My idea is:

1. Create a small partial
2. Create a small controller
3. Insert the partial n times into the main page and inject the subobject into the controller

How can this be done?

Comment: You say you want the sub-objects on specific places on the page which means you need to do that **manually**, But then you want to insert the partial n times. Please give more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a directive. It can have specific inputs (the `scope` configuration), the desired common template, and any functionality in the link function or the controller. Directives seem intimidating at first, but they are the tool for the job and *very* powerful. In your case it could simply be:

```
app.directive("editor", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            item: "=" // input
        },
        template: "..." // the template you want, or alternatively a templateUrl
    };
});
```

And used as:

```
<div editor="" item="data.first"></div>
```

An example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g9jbh/

Comment: Obviously it cannot be done without a custom directive. That was my assumption too. Thanks for all the prompt answers and examples.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of hard to tell from your question as it stands now, but I think you want a directive with an isolated scope.

A directive can have:

1. An isolated scope so it can affect part or all of your object
2. Its own controller
3. can have its own template (partial)